# Designated Initializer of UITextView

Tags: xcode, uitextview, swift, initializer

When I create a new subclass of `UITextView` in the Xcode 6 Beta, the following code is automatically provided.

```
import UIKit

class TerminalView: UITextView {

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // Initialization code
    }
}
```

The previous code (completely provided by Xcode with nothing removed) gives the following error.

`Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UITextView'`

As far as I know, the designated for all subclasses of `UIView` is `-initWithFrame:` (or in Swift, `init(frame:)`. If this is the case, **why does the code provided by Xcode result in an error?** I have added no new instance variables to the class, so nothing else has to be initialized yet.

Comment: Submitted bug. #17472321 for anyone wanted to check the status.

Comment: still not fixed

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems as though the only initializer that works for now is:

```
super.init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?)
```

which can be called with

```
super.init(frame: CGRect.zero, textContainer: nil)
```

This is most likely a bug in the initial beta release and will be fixed in upcoming beta releases.

Answer (score 12):

## For 2020:

```
class SpecialText: UITextView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        common()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        common()
    }
    
    private func common() {
        backgroundColor = .yellow
        font = .systemFont(ofSize: 26)
        textColor = .green
    }
}
```